# Is there a faster solution to splitting string into words from dictionary

Tags: string, hash, split, dynamic-programming

Given a string *s* and array *a* of words, split *s* using words from *a* so that the least characters were left without matching to any of words.
So given `s = 'aabbac'` and `a = {'aabb', 'c', 'aab', 'bac'}` I expect *s* to be splited into **aab**|**bac** not into **aabb**|a|**c** because the last option gives me an extra character.
Is there any solutions faster than *O(|s|*|a|)* with dynamic programming and hashes?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that optimal processing involves scanning through s from left to right, using a trie to track matching words in a, keeping partial solutions in a vector or similar along with an indication of whether they currently are part-way through matching some part of the trie, or are waiting to start a new match, and the cummulative count of characters matched so far.  You'd have to expand the vector when alternative matches/terminations are found, and you can "condense" all entries that aren't mid-match to an arbitrary selection therefrom with the (equal) highest cummulative count.  I don't see any use for hashes - that implies something far slower than a trie - extracting and testing candidate words without any clear idea whether you're already "inside" a partial match.